# Android app development with android auto. Problem with view when displayed on different devices

Tags: java, android, html, xml, android-constraintlayout

I am fairly new to the android development. I tried developing an app that displays multiplication table. I am developing it entirely on Android Virtual Device(Pixel 6 Pro), but when I tried to run it on my Physical Device(OnePlus 9 Pro) the view got kind of messed up. On AVD the table is complete from 1-10 while on Physical Device its only 1-8. Can someone find the error. Following is the xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editnum"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.206" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editnum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.695"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Generate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the value of textView?  The number of vertical pixels are different.  See : https://www.tomsguide.com/news/google-pixel-6-pro-vs-oneplus-9-pro-which-android-phone-wins

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because of different device sizes. The `TextView` is having the entire table but it is not showing due to smaller device screen. If you could scroll your screen you would be able to see the remaining contents, but you cannot scroll a `TextView` by default. You can make it scrollable in two ways:

**1. Using `ScrollView`**

ScrollView is a view group that is used to make scrollable views. A scroll view contains a single direct child only.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_TEXT_VIEW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Note: You can set constraints to the scroll view as you like.

**2. Programmatically**

Set this property to your `TextView` in the layout file.

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

and then use this code to make it scrollable.

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```